# Creating a modal window onload of a page for user feedback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

I have to create a modal window to display a popup or a modal window to get the feedback from the user for our intranet. This window should have a checkbox which says "do not ask this question again".
I tried creating this window using jquery but I dont understand how to do it. I even tried to google it but not getting proper answers. Can anyone please help me with this. 
I am new to jquery.I have seen many sites where they have created modal windows but they use php and I cant. Please help me with jquery, jsp or javascript code for this purpose.
A screenshot from the use case document is attached.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
p.s. I am using websphere portal.

Sorry the image wasnt allowed..

The below mentioned code also doenst work. Plz help.

```
    <html>
<head>
<%@page session="false" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*,javax.portlet.*,com.ibm.accessitservicesfeedbackpopup.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet"%>        
<%@taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/portal/v6.1/portlet-client-model" prefix="portlet-client-model" %>        
<portlet:defineObjects/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= renderRequest.getContextPath() %>/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= renderRequest.getContextPath() %>/jqModal.css"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%= renderRequest.getContextPath() %>/jqModal.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function confirm(msg,callback) {
  $('#confirm')
    .jqmShow()
    .find('p.jqmConfirmMsg')
      .html(msg)
    .end()
    .find(':submit:visible')
      .click(function(){
        if(this.value == 'yes')
          (typeof callback == 'string') ?
            window.location.href = callback :
            callback();
        $('#confirm').jqmHide();
      });
}


$().ready(function() {
  $('#confirm').jqm({overlay: 88, modal: true, trigger: false});

  // trigger a confirm whenever links of class alert are pressed.
  $('a.confirm').click(function() { 
    confirm('About to visit: '+this.href+' !',this.href); 
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="jqModal">view</a> (confirm)

<!-- Confirm Dialog -->
<div class="jqmWindow" id="confirm">

<div id="ex3b" class="jqmConfirmWindow">
    <div class="jqmConfirmTitle clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="jqmClose"><em>Close</em></a>
  </div>

  <div class="jqmConfirmContent">
  <p class="jqmConfirmMsg"></p>
  <p>Continue?</p>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="no" />
  <input type="submit" value="yes" />

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please have a look at http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/. Here you can show any section (div) of your page as a Modal popup. So, your form will be shown as modal popup.

Comment: 1) include jqmodal.js in page, 2) initialize section id (<div> which has the section to show as popup) in document ready of jquery 3) the section <div> must contain class="jqmWindow" 4) the link (view) must contain class "jqModal". Is this perfect in your case?

Comment: Hi felix, Thanks a lot for quick response but the above mentioned code doesnt work. Any idea why???

Comment: If possible, please provide fiddle

Comment: did you include the CSS as well?

Comment: Hi Felix, Sorry I am still missing something. Can you please help with the example by writing the code. Please

Comment: Yes I did include the css.. Sorry what is fiddle?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Z6pLU/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is nice jQuery dialog you can use. Just download jQuery and jquery ui (both js and css) and include to your project. It works prefectlly.

Comment: Felix and alexey thanks for explaining but unfortunately it still doesnt work. It just shows the link and when I click on the link, it just does nothing. Any other advice???